# How to print a List of Arrays (with elements) using Java 8 Streams?

Tags: java, java-8

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    List<Integer> numbers2 = Arrays.asList(3,4);

    List<int[]> intPairs = numbers1.stream()
            .flatMap(i -> numbers2.stream()
                    .filter(j -> (i+j)%3 == 0)
                    .map(j -> new int[]{i,j}))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    intPairs.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

For the above code, I am getting output as:

```
[I@214c265e
[I@448139f0
```

But my expectation is to get `[(2, 4), (3, 3)]`.

Could you please guide me to achieve this?

Comment: Could change the last line to: intPairs.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the mapping part to `List` instead of using `int[]`:

```
....
.map(j -> Arrays.asList(i,j)))
....
```

And the output will be the following:

```
[2, 4]
[3, 3]
```

Here is the complete example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    List<Integer> numbers2 = Arrays.asList(3,4);

    List<List<Integer>> intPairs = numbers1.stream()
            .flatMap(i -> numbers2.stream()
                    .filter(j -> (i+j)%3 == 0)
                    .map(j -> Arrays.asList(i,j)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    intPairs.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @arsen-davtyan, it serves my purpose well.
But I was bit reluctant using List here.
Instead I wanted the solution something like:-

{List<String> intPairs = numbers1.stream()
    .flatMap(i -> numbers2.stream()
      .filter(j -> (i+j)%3 == 0)
      .map(j -> Arrays.toString(new int[]{i,j})))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());}